# Drupal: drupal_get_form specify file to search

Tags: php, file, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-webform

How to specify file to search for a function drupal_get_form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [include_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) , [require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) or [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) for adding files where the form resides . drupal_get_form automatically takes care to include the form.

for example :

```
include_once drupal_get_path('module', 'modname') .'/file.php';
```

Answer (score 4):

If you mean a form used as page callback, the `file` parameter is where you can specify a filename:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu().
 */
function MODULENAME_menu(){
    return array(
        'my/form' => array(
            'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
            'page arguments' => array('MODULENAME_myform'),
            'file' => 'myform.inc',
            //
            // ...
            //
        ),
    );
}
```

In that example, the function "`MODULENAME_myform`" that returns the form structure that `drupal_get_form` uses to build the page "`www.yoursite.com/my/form`" is stored in the file "`myform.inc`".